# Sort Heroku logs chronologically

Tags: linux, open-source, logs, bash

Heroku is a hosting platform whose logs can be accessed via the `heroku logs` command line:

```
$ heroku logs
2014-07-17T06:24:02.216403+00:00 app[web.1]: Started
2014-07-17T06:24:02.216410+00:00 app[web.1]: Stopped
2014-07-17T06:24:02.216408+00:00 app[web.1]: Paused
```

As you can notice above, the [chronological order is not respected](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-message-ordering).
Heroku is happy with that and gives no particular advice.

Is there any tool or bash script that I can use to have Heroku logs sorted?
The logs are pretty small, 1500 lines max.

Free, Open source, runs in Linux bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Gilles, this is the easiest and works flawlessly:

```
heroku logs | sort
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
heroku logs > heroku.txt
sort -n -t\  -k1 heroku.txt
```

The `-n` is sorting numbers in order, `-t\` bit is using a space as a separator, `-k1` is using column one (the timestamp).

Without putting the logs in a separate file I assume you could use:

```
heroku logs | sort -n -t\  -k1
```

Similarly, to sort in reverse order (`-nr`):

```
heroku logs | sort -nr -t\  -k1
```

Comment: That works! I actually need chronological order, so could you please change to `heroku logs | sort -n -t\  -k1`? Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) Changed that for you.

Comment: `heroku logs | sort` would work just as well. The date format has the property that lexicographic order matches chronological order, thanks to the fields being fixed-width and in order of decreasing significance.

Comment: You're quite right - never noticed that! Learn something new every day..

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a little script to make live logs (`heroku logs -t`) sorted.

http://pastebin.com/8Lby3bMg

You can run with:

```
heroku logs -t | python delayed_sort.py
```

If you want to keep the coloring:

```
script -q -c "heroku logs -t" -a /dev/null | python delayed_sort.py
```

The script simply holds a buffer of the last 100 log lines. When the buffer gets full the line with the oldest timestamp is popped out (using heap-queue for efficiency...).
The buffer is also flushed out when there are no new log lines for 1 second.

There is still a tiny chance that the lines will come out unsorted: a line with a timestamp that is older than the 100 preceding lines, or a line with an old timestamp after a 1 second communication pause.

Comment: Great! Maybe the script could call heroku logs by itself, so that I just have to invoke the script only, without using pipes?

Comment: The script would work for any pipe of logs that contain timestamps. It could be a nice heroku-cli-plugin ( https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-cli-plugins ), but I think you would have to convert the code to Ruby or something. I simply created a bash script in my PATH called `heroku-logs`, with the `script -q ...` line.

Comment: This script doesn't work on Mac OSX due to select.poll() not being supported.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740471/cannot-use-python-select-poll-in-mac-os